# How to detect an ADB interface device in windows?

Tags: android, windows, driver, adb

Is there any way to detect an android adb interface device in windows. I want to install an adb interface driver automatically. Thanks.

Comment: Install Either OEM driver or make one by hand as in:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709263/google-android-usb-driver-and-adb

Answer (score 0):

Question is not much clear. Any how i will say what i know, it may help you.

You have to install Android SDK, it will include all tools required for Android development.
The below link will give information about ADB.

[Android Debug Bridge (ADB)](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html)

Answer (score -1):

it is not automatically even in the latest android studio IDE.

You should install it by yourself. Here is the link:
http://adbdriver.com/downloads/

after installing it, my Android mobile phone Can be applied for online debugging in android studi.